# Show Modal State Errors one after the other on Button click

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-modal, modelstate

[image: Login]

I have been trying to show modal state errors one after the other in modal popup but in MVC, modal error will get displayed as soon as we hit Submit button as shown in above image.

My problem is, i want to show this Validation Error message one after the other that is when User first click Sign In button it should ask to Enter User Name and Once user fill UserName and click Submit, it should ask for Entering Password.
Here goes i code:

```
    <div id="ModalLogin" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dtModalLogin" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header paddingTopBottom-5">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="ModalLogin">Validation Errors</h4>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body alert-danger">
                <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-xs-2">
                      <i class="fa fa-warning fa-3x"></i>
                   </div>
               <div class="col-xs-10">
            <div>
         <h4> 
         @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Please fill the Mandatory fields as shown below:")
         </h4>
      </div>
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
                </div>
```

My View Design:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Login.UserName, new { @placeholder = "UserName", @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Login.UserName, "*")
            <br />
            @Html.PasswordFor(Model => Model.Login.Password, new { @placeholder = "Password", @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Login.Password, "*")
            <br />
            <input id="btnLogin" type="submit" class="btn text-muted text-center btn-success" value="Sign in" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalLogin" />
```

My Controller Method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(ViewModel objView)
    {
if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
//To do something
}
}
```

Comment: the validation is done on post or using jquery validation?

Comment: Write your own validation framework - `@Html.ValidationSummary()` displays **all** validation errors!

Comment: @StephenMuecke are you talking about writing HtmlHelper?

Comment: @Arijit, Validation is done on post on submit button click.

Comment: In that case you can select firstordefault in model.isValid fail

Comment: @StephenMuecke, there is no override method so that i can make use of existing instead of writing Manually as it leads to extra time utilization for writing validation.

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee, any link or example which i can refer??

Comment: i don't know buddy let me check

Comment: @Rajesh, What is the point of this. Why would you not inform the user of all errors?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, my senior asked me to do that, and i can't argue rather than first trying by myself.

Comment: @Rajesh the validation is using jquery validattion and not post actionresult

Comment: @Rajesh, The error messages in `ValidationSummary()` are displayed in a `<ul>` element. It utter nonsense, but you could use javascript to remove all its `<li>` elements except the first one. But you also have  a `ValidationMessageFor()` for each property so as soon as the modal is dismissed, the other errors are displayed anyway!